# Problemas ao filtrar campo com LIKE em MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho uma tabela que possui mais de 1 milhão de dados que quero filtrar por meio de uma sigla que pode estar em qualquer parte da String do campo. A mesma possui index BTREE no MySQL. Estou fazendo desta forma:

```
select instituicao, count(instituicao)
from base_wos
WHERE instituicao LIKE '%{$Sigla}%' GROUP BY instituicao limit 1250000;
```

Ao executar esta query não obtenho retorno, sendo que a mesma possui quantidade diferente de zero no banco.

Estou usando a ferramenta Workbench do MySQL.

Comment: Essa query está dentro de um PHP?

Comment: Estou usando o próprio WorkBench do MySQL.

Comment: Na verdade cade o Group By instituição ? e {$sigla} o WorkBench não vai entender só no PHP isso ...

Comment: Esqueci de pôr aqui mais está com o group sim.

Comment: Foi por causa desse trecho estranho que perguntei se estava usando PHP: `'%{$Sigla}%'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema dessa forma:

```
select instituicao, count(*)
from base_wos
WHERE instituicao LIKE '%Sigla%' GROUP BY instituicao limit 1250000;
```

O problema era a sintaxe do PHP sendo usada no SQL por engano. O Like usa apenas `%` como coringa, e a substring tem que ser escrita literalmente.